# Algorithm to find minimum weight perfect matching in a complete directed weighted graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, discrete-optimization, spectral-graph-theory, matching-theory

We have a complete weighted and directed graph $G(H,E)$. Is there a polynomial algorithm to find a minimum weight perfect matching in the graph $G$?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the direction of edges has no sense in the matching problem. And then there is a [polynomial solution](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.228.2937&rep=rep1&type=pdf).